# Limit login attempt with servlet and database

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to limit the number of attempts a user could try to login with servlet, but it just doesn't show the "blocked account" after 3 attempts. How could I solve this? Please help.

Here's my code:

```
int maxAttempts;
            maxAttempts = 0;
             while(maxAttempts < 3)
               {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");


        HttpSession session = request.getSession();



        if(LoginConnection.checkUser(username, password))
        {

            session.setAttribute("username", username);

            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("profile.jsp");
            rs.forward(request, response);
            break;
        }
        else
        {  
            String error = "Invalid password";
            request.setAttribute("error", error);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);   
            maxAttempts++;
            break;


               }



        } if(maxAttempts == 3) {
            String error = "Blocked account.";
            request.setAttribute("error", error);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);   


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put max attempts in session. Don't use while. Only if else. Put the last if block in else

Before the if block get the max attempts from session and increment it and put it back in session in the if block